What should I be aware of concerning wild boars as a tourist in Spain during mating season?
In less than 2 weeks, I'm going on my yearly vacation to Spain that I mentioned in other questions on Travel Stack Exchange. Today, one of my relatives who is already there shared a picture of him and his partner encountering several wild boars. They were walking along a nearby road that's adjacent to a small protected wetlands area around an old salt mine, where we've in the past seen boar tracks and even heard wild boar sleeping, and at the entrance to the walking route in that wetlands area were three boars foraging. We've also seen videos on Facebook of boars foraging around the same area.
I live in a suburban area in Flanders and as such am not really familiar with wild animals beyond the occasional squirrel, rat, mouse or pigeon. Hence, I don't really know what to do or how to handle larger animals like this. I know that they can be surprisingly dangerous when provoked. I also know that the period when I'm there is right in the middle of mating season for wild boar, but I don't know to what extent that impacts their behavior.
What advice do you have for me regarding these animals?

Here are some recommendations. It does not sound like they are particularly dangerous animals, though they are certainly capable of causing harm if surprised, cornered or seriously injured (or if you threaten their young). 3 of the 4 boar-related deaths in the US in the past 150 years were as a result of an injured boar in a hunting situation. Maybe you'll find  jabalíes on the menu.

I had to break hard on my bike once to not crash into piglets crossing the bike path just after their mama.  I don't want to imagine what would have happened had I crashed into one of them.  This was in The Netherlands.

In general, you should not bother much. They are used to humans, and they just run away, just at a safe distance and they will return. At my home, I wake up several night (years ago) to scare them out of my small vineyard, and it was nearly a mission impossible: they just run on one side. I go on that side and they run on the other side. They do not care about me, and I was trying to scare them. And they had the small "children" (very cute).
I observed the family for many weeks (trying to keep them away, finding where they passed trough the fence (and electric fence). I think I counted 3 adults, 5 or more "smaller one", and more then 10 small ones. I never felt they would attack me, and I was trying hard to scare them. They know the humans (they know very well that near humans there is much food, and with babies, the easy food is good). Note: they tend to move on evening, night and early morning. During the days it is difficult to find them, and also to disturb them.
On woods: if you keep the paths, it should not be a problem, but I prefer to make some noise (and speak to myself from time to time if I'm alone) if I see that wild boars were nearby (recent holes in ground). Outside paths I do much more noise. Just to be sure they are not surprised to see me (and probably the contrary: that I didn't get surprised if they suddenly run away from me).
And check locals about other dangers. I usually wear red. I'm more scared about boar hunters compared to wild boars.

Just looked for boar attacks in France, and while some do get listed, it seems that it often happens when boar hunters get attacked by their quarry.
